# What are reference counted variables in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, global-variables, freepascal, local-variables, delphi-12-athens

I know what normal global variables and local variables are, but what are "local reference-counted" variables and "local non reference-counted" variables?

What is it? What's the difference? How do they work?

Can someone show code examples and explain please?

Comment: When a reference-counted variables reference count goes down to zero, it is freed automatically. But in what context have you stumbled on the terminology?

Comment: If you know what a local variable is, and you know what a reference counted variable is, then you know everything. Is your question therefore, "what is a reference counter variable?"

Comment: Perhaps that is what my question should be David. I don't know what a reference counter variable is. I'll adjust my question.

Comment: Reference-counted and non-reference-counted for this type of variable means that the variable's type is a reference-counted type (e.g. string or interface) or not a reference counted type(e.g. integer or double). For local variables that makes a difference in whether they are automatically initialized (reference-counted) or not (non-reference-counted). In the latter case they will contain garbage if not explicitly initizlized in code.

Comment: I think you meant reference counte*d* variable, didn't you?

Comment: Look at RAD Studio Help. Select the `Index` tab and type `Internal Data Formats (Delphi)`. Select that item from the list beneath. Scroll down until you find `Long String Types`. There's a drawing of the internal structure of `Unicode String` showing among others `ReferenceCount`. The text explains shortly what the ref. count is and in a code block a few rows down it shows with an actual example how it works. Dynamic array types also use reference counters. It may be useful to also look at the other data types.

Comment: It is not exactly clear whether you are asking about what is reference counting in general or you are just interested on its impact on local variables. Maybe it would be more clear if you would provide more context about what prompted you to ask this question. In other words, are you asking  about memory management techniques in general and comparison between manual memory management and automatic reference counting, or you are interested in difference local variables initialization which depends on variable type.

Answer (score 3):

A reference-counted object maintains an internal counter of how many variables refer to it at runtime.  Delphi native types that have reference counting include the string types `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString`, as well as `interface`s and dynamic arrays.

Such types are automatically managed by the Delphi compiler for you. Multiple variables of these types can refer to the same object in memory.  When a managed variable refers to an existing object, the compiler increases <sup>1</sup> the object's counter.  When that variable no longer refers to the object, because it was reassigned or went out of scope, the compiler decreases <sup>1</sup> the object's counter.

<sup>1: unless the variable is `const`, then it doesn't.</sup>

When an object's counter falls to zero, meaning no more variables refer to it, then the compiler frees the object from memory.